# Create a new table based on value of another table?

Tags: powerbi

I have data relating to Employee name, start and end date, number of shares granted per each year, and number of years the scheme is going to go for.

For example, Employee A has been granted 5000 shares for 4 years on 1st April 2020 and it has vesting period on 1st april 2021,1st april 2022 and 1st april 2023 and 1st april 2024

The data given by the client will have only the Employee name, start and end date (1st April 2020
and 1st April 2024 , number of shares granted per each year (5000) and number of years the scheme is going to vest (4years). It will look like this

[image]

Is it possible to create a new table  like this in power bi based on the above table
[image]

I have been able to use this formula in power bi

let
StDt = [#"Grant date #(lf)(dd/mm/yyyy)"],
AllDates = {Number.From([#"Grant date #(lf)(dd/mm/yyyy)"])..Number.From([#"Vesting end date#(lf)(dd/mm/yyyy)"])},

StofMonthDates =
List.Distinct(List.Select(List.InsertRange(List.Transform(AllDates, each Date.StartOfYear(Date.From(*))),0,{[#"Grant date #(lf)(dd/mm/yyyy)"]}),each Number.From (*) >= Number.From(StDt)))
in
StofMonthDates

But since im using the start of the year fucntion it is giving me January 1st and i want it to give the same date as per grant date and only the year should change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: You could create a new table with following code:

```
Year_Table = 
    GENERATE(
        YourTable,
         FILTER(
             SELECTCOLUMNS(
                 GENERATESERIES(1, 100),
                    "ID", [Value],
                    "End date", DATE(YEAR(YourTable[Grand date]) + [Value], MONTH(YourTable[Grand date]), DAY(YourTable[Grand date]))
                 ),
            [ID] <= YourTable[Vesting period]
            )
        )
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Update**, now for each month:

```
Month_Table = 
    GENERATE(
        YourTable,
         FILTER(
             SELECTCOLUMNS(
                 GENERATESERIES(1, 100),
                    "ID", [Value] / 12,
                    "End date", DATE(YEAR(YourTable[Grand date]), MONTH(YourTable[Grand date]) + [Value], DAY(YourTable[Grand date]))
                 ),
            [ID] <= YourTable[Vesting period]
            )
        )
```

Comment: But the vesting end date should be from the grant date to the vesting end date. Like i have add years based on grant date and vesting period and expand the rows

Comment: I've updated my solution. Please check.

Comment: found a mistake, now it's fine

Comment: Thanks man it worked! and additional doubt it is okay to ask

Comment: I need to generate the dates between grant date and the end date as per your file. Is it possible to do it based on the generate function?

Comment: So you want 365 rows per Employee or what do you mean?

Comment: Yes like how i generated for each years. now i want to generate each month between the grant date and end date per employee

Comment: I've add another update, pleas try :-)

Comment: Hey sorry but it was not working it through an error "The expression refers to multiple columns. Multiple columns cannot be converted to a scalar value."

Comment: Master data (expanded) = GENERATE('Master data',FILTER(SELECTCOLUMNS(GENERATESERIES(1,100),"ID",[Value]/12 ," Month date",DATE(YEAR('Master data'[Grant date (dd/mm/yyyy)]), MONTH('Master data'[Grant date (dd/mm/yyyy)]) +[Value],DAY('Master data'[Grant date (dd/mm/yyyy)]))),[ID]<='Master data'[Vesting period(in years)]))

Comment: Ok, in my case it worked with the test data. You have tested it on the same data where the yearly approach worked? I don't see any mistakes in your code.

Comment: yes i used the same formula and it is saying "The expression refers to multiple columns. Multiple columns cannot be converted to a scalar value."

Comment: Have you tried to create a new column instead a new table?

Comment: oh, yes man. I need to create a new column. It will work only if i want to create a new table ah? I have been stupid here. Sorry man

Comment: Yes because a new column cannot multiply rows :-) So in your case you could create a yearly, monthly, daily table. With the daily you might to increase the number in the generator (1000 instead of 100).

Comment: I need to generate the months between grant date and end date in a new column after creating the table as you suggested in the first place. So sorry man

Comment: No problem, if it works for you please accept the answer.

Comment: If I want to multiply rows for both the years and then based on years, create news rows for months. It is not possible ah?

Comment: You could create the month solution and add another column with `Year = YEAR([End Date])`. Then you're having both.

Comment: It is not giving the vesting end date. It is giving the year of the end date only

Comment: Ok, in that case `Year_End = DATE(YEAR('YourTable'[End date]) , 12,31)`

Comment: Can you help me out with this alone?

Comment: let StDt = [#"Grant date #(lf)(dd/mm/yyyy)"], AllDates = {Number.From([#"Grant date #(lf)(dd/mm/yyyy)"])..Number.From([#"Vesting end date#(lf)(dd/mm/yyyy)"])},

StofMonthDates = List.Distinct(List.Select(List.InsertRange(List.Transform(AllDates, each Date.StartOfYear(Date.From())),0,{[#"Grant date #(lf)(dd/mm/yyyy)"]}),each Number.From () >= Number.From(StDt))) in StofMonthDates

Comment: In that code which i used. "each Date.StartOfYear" if i use this,i'm getting the start of the year. but is it possible to get the grant date and add years on it

Comment: Oh but this is Power Query now. I'd might be good to open a new topic for that, what do you think? Otherwise it's getting a bit cluttered.

Comment: yeah you are correct.

Comment: Month_Table = 
    GENERATE(
        YourTable,
         FILTER(
             SELECTCOLUMNS(
                 GENERATESERIES(1, 100),
                    "ID", [Value] / 12,
                    "End date", DATE(YEAR(YourTable[Grand date]), MONTH(YourTable[Grand date]) + [Value], DAY(YourTable[Grand date]))
                 ),
            [ID] <= YourTable[Vesting period]
            )
        )

Comment: With regards to the above measure, can you tell me if it is possible to alter this to create the create a month list with start date of each month. If yes, my problem is solved

Comment: I'm not a great expert in Query M. Could this help you: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/M-Query-Add-list-of-months-between-dates/td-p/1650103

Comment: I understand. i was asking based on the measure which you suggested

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit in a rush and I don't know if I get it correctly. `DATE()` you can do something similar to `StartsOfMonth` or `StartsOfYear`. The `DATE()` function has three parameter. Year, Month and Day. If you say `DATE(YEAR([Grand Date], 1,1)` your getting the beginning of the year. Same with month `DATE(YEAR([Grand Date], MONTH([Grand Date],1)`